# pfsense: Prohibit all outbound connectivity from inside going out, except for one system's traffic

Tags: firewall, pfsense

I've got a lab environment here for some testing of software which should only run on this "lab environment" network.

To that end, the "lab environment" has a pfsense firewall sitting on the periphery of the network, acting as the "gateway".

I need to set pfSense to prohibit all internal LAN addresses from connecting outbound to the Internet, with the exception of a single system which has an IP addressed to it statically.

I have tried blocking `FROM LAN Address -> (any)` with no luck, as the system has still been able to reach out to the internet with that rule.  Creating a "Pass" rule is easy enough for this, I think, `FROM 172.16.1.1 TO (any)`.

Can someone help me out with these firewall rules?  Kinda new to pfSense, as I come from an `iptables`-at-the-network-edge environment, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't block "LAN Address", you need to block "LAN Subnet".

Do the following:

- Add a rule as the first rule: `PASS, 172.16.1.1 -> ANY`
- Add a rule as the second rule: `DENY, LAN subnet -> ANY`

Comment: *\*facepalms** God I feel stupid now for not noticing the `LAN subnet` option in the rules.  Thanks for the help, these rules are working now.

Comment: Don't worry, happens to the best of us. have fun

Comment: hate to pick your brain again, but can a similar rule be made to prevent interfaces/subnets from communicating with each other?  we don't want machines on the LAN interface and machines on the OPT1 interface to communicate with each other, is it as simple as `DENY LAN subnet -> OPT1 subnet` and `DENY OPT1 subnet -> LAN subnet`?

Comment: Yes, it's as simple as that :) Just do it on the correct interface! (Deny LAN on LAN interface, Deny OPT1 on OPT1 Interface)